# Prove that almost surely $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_n}{\ln n}=\frac{1}{\lambda}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, exponential-distribution, almost-everywhere

Let ${(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}}$, be independent random variables distributed $Exp(\lambda)$.

Prove that almost surely $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_n}{\ln n}=\frac{1}{\lambda}$$
My idea was to look at the $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P\left(\left|\frac{X_k}{\ln k}-\frac{1}{\lambda}\right|>\epsilon\right)$$ and prove it is finite. But I think it is not.
$$P\left(X_k<\left(-\epsilon+\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)\ln k\right)=\frac{1}{k}(1-k^{\lambda\epsilon})$$ and we can take such espilon value so it is divergent as $k\to\infty$, which means sum does not converge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe that for $c>0$, we have that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(X_n>c\log n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{\lambda c}}=\begin{cases}
<\infty&\text{if }c>1/\lambda\\
\infty&\text{if }c<1/\lambda
\end{cases}\quad (1)
$$
where we used the fact that $P(X>x)=e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\geq 0$ if $X\sim \text{exp}(\lambda)$. It follows by Borel-Cantelli that for each $\varepsilon>0$
$$
P\left(\frac{X_n}{\log n}>\lambda^{-1}+\varepsilon\quad \text{i.o}\right)=0
$$
whence
$$
\limsup \frac{X_n}{\log n}\leq \lambda^{-1}.
$$
with probability $1$. Similarly for each $\varepsilon>0$,
$$
P\left(\frac{X_n}{\log n}>\lambda^{-1}-\varepsilon\quad \text{i.o}\right)=1
$$
whence
$$
\limsup \frac{X_n}{\log n}\geq \lambda^{-1}.$$
with probability $1$.

Comment: thanks! :) nice work